# Magento2 product images not showing but are still in the media folder

Tags: magento2, product-images

We have a recurring problem on a **Magento2** store, where all of the product images do not show. We see the **Magento** default placeholder.

Previously, we have manually uploaded every image through Magento admin, and they show fine for x months until they disappear again.

**Any advice on getting to the route of what is causing the issue?**

Also advice on how to quickly remedy the issue and upload all images again without doing manually 1 by 1?

**The images are still in the file locations, but below database table is empty:**

> catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value

Our plan at the moment is to restore this table from latest backup or go back to a backup before issue occurred.

Comment: We've updated the database table catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value which now has the fields filled with the location of the image. But still the images don't show in Magento2 admin area or frontend. Any ideas to debug further?